# Can be exif data laid outside of app1 marker segment?

Tags: c, jpeg, exif, libjpeg

I want to add support EXIF for libjpeg library. I read exif2.2 specification briefly, but it does not contain any information about possiblity of exif tag's value, which can be located outside of APP1 marker segment (for example after end of file marker). Is that situation possible?

Comment: If you already use a library to read the JPG images, why not try to find another library for the EXIF data?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I thought about that. But many libraries to work with jpeg/exif are not suited for commercial uses. The only library I found which can be used in such way is ImageMagick. Maybe I will use it, if implementation of exif will be too difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain the `metadata-extractor` library, in [Java](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) and [C#](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet), and have never seen Exif data outside of `APP1`. It's possible that there are more than one `APP1` segments, so you should check for, then skip, the six-byte preamble: `Exif\0\0`.

If you find a JPEG image that has Exif data outside of the `APP1` segment, I'd very much like to know about it!

Comment: Great thanks! That assumption will make parsing/writing more easy

Comment: I have a photo where the second `APP1` segment does not contain `Exif\0\0`.  The first 30 bytes are:`http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/\0`.

Comment: @Deanie that looks like the XMP preamble.